# Pricebook field auto population in Quote Record Salesforcec CPQ

Tags: managed-package, opportunity, cpq, pricebook

Pricebook field (Pricebook2Id)is auto populated on opportunity record by a visual workflow that looks up the right pricebook record from pricebook object based on an account field in the opportunity record.

[image: Opportunity pricebook field]

Now my problem is that this pricebook field is auto populated on the quote record upon creating a new quote from the opportunity.
[image: Quote pricebook field]

I  have checked workflows,process builder,flows, trigger,formula field to see  how this field is being auto populated.But i couldn't find it being used anywhere.

Now my question is whether salesforce CPQ automatically populates this field from a managed package trigger.

I am very new to CPQ and not sure how else this field is being populated.

Pls help!

Comment: When you create a quote from Opp, the price-book id from Opp is copied over the quote.

Comment: Yes,Thank you. Any idea how it is auto populated?

Comment: Salesforce does it automatically.

Comment: Can this functionality be overridden?

Comment: Nope, but why you want to override it?

Comment: Currently the pricebook in opportunity obj is populated from Account using flow. The requirement is to populate pricebook field in quote obj directly from Account obj

Comment: you need to populate it in the Opportunity first, then it will flow into Quote automatically.